# Finding Surface area of Paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble finding the surface area of the part of the paraboloid that lies in the first octant of $z=5-x^2-y^2$.

So, I realized that the first octant refers to when, $x,y,z \ge 0$. How do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** parametrize the paraboloid using cylindrical coordinates: $${\bf x}(u,v) = (u \cos v, u \sin v, 5 - u^2),$$with $0 \leq u \leq \sqrt{5}$ and $0 \leq v \leq \pi/2$. Then compute: $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^\sqrt{5}\|{\bf x}_u \times {\bf x}_v\|\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v.$$

---

You don't actually need to compute the cross product explictly: We have that: $${\bf x}_u(u,v) = (\cos v, \sin v, -2u), \quad {\bf x}_v(u,v) = (-u\sin v, u \cos v, 0).$$Call $E = \langle {\bf x}_u,{\bf x}_u\rangle$, $F = \langle {\bf x}_u,{\bf x}_v\rangle$ and $G = \langle {\bf x}_v,{\bf x}_v \rangle$. Then: $$\|{\bf x}_u \times {\bf x}_v\| = \sqrt{EG-F^2},$$by [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Comment: Can you add more if you can?

Comment: Try to do it on your own first. If you get stuck, say exactly where and I'll point you in the right way.

Comment: I know that this will sound bad, but I'm having trouble calculating the cross product.

Comment: It is possible to compute $\|{\bf x}_u \times {\bf x}_v\|$ without computing ${\bf x}_u \times {\bf x}_v$ first. I added some details on that in the answer.

Comment: What does it mean to do EG?

Comment: They're numbers.

Comment: I know but how exactly do you compute that?

Comment: Did you read what I added in the answer? I just gave the expressions to computing $E,F$ and $G$.

Comment: Would you consider helping me with this step by step to ensure that I can learn this well?

Comment: Or can you tell me what the final answer comes out to so I can verify?

Comment: You can set the integral up and check it on Wolfram Alpha, for example.

Comment: Can you please give me one more hint?

Comment: Is the final answer $\frac{\pi}{24}(21\sqrt{21}-1)$?